# Prevent access to parent URL but not its children

Tags: apache, debian

On a Debian VPS I run an Apache 2.4.56 web server and I want to prevent any access to a parent URL, for instance

`https://example.com/participants`

while allowing access to any of its children, for instance

`https://example.com/participants/joebloggs`

`https://example.com/participants/janedoe`

`https://example.com/participants/johndoe`

The parent URL I want to block is a db-generated page that shows a listing of all the users. I do not want to serve this page, only its children.

I tried the following in my `apache2.conf`

```
<Location /participants>
   Order Allow,Deny
</Location>
<Location /participants/*>
   Order Deny,Allow
</Location>
```

and

```
<Location /participants/>
        Options None
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Location>

<LocationMatch /participants/*>
        Require all granted
</LocationMatch>
```

but both sets of directives return `301 - Forbidden` for both parent and children URLs.

What's the right approach?

Comment: What powers the contents of `/participants`?  Is it a directory listing?  Is it an directory index file (`index.html`)?  Is there a rewrite rule that passed it to some code?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller if by 'directory' you mean an actual directory then no. `participants` is a db-generated page that shows a listing of all the users, which I do not want to serve. Does that answer your question?
P.S. updated my OP with what you were asking.

Comment: It might be easier to modify the code to throw an exception rather than generate that page.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Site is in PHP. You mean change the PHP code? I did that already, but I thought blocking it at Apache level would be better. It seems that Googlebot was still picking up users that have no way of being indexed as they have no material published. Anyway, in the meantime I tried a directive that seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These directives seem to do the job

```
<LocationMatch "^/participants/$">
    Require all denied
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch "^/participants/[^/]+$">
    Require all granted
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: I'll bet you don't need the second directive.  In fact, it could interefere with some other directive that requires password, or blocks access to something in that directory.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller thx... I will test it without